# Cloud Run dies in middle of request and returns 400

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I have the following code in my `main.py` for a Cloud Run service.

```py
import json
import os

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from google.cloud import storage
from flask import Flask, request
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.engine.url import URL


app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/", methods=["POST"])
def index():
    obj = request.values.get("object-id")
    obj_bucket = request.values.get("object-bucket")
    print("[" + obj + "]" + " request received")
    # Validate the message has good data
    if obj == "" or obj_bucket == "":
        msg = "Invalid args"
        return f"Bad Request: {msg}", 400

    try:
        # Retrieve object and download locally
        print("[" + obj + "]" + " connecting to storage")
        storage_client = storage.Client()
        bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(obj_bucket)
        blob = bucket.blob(obj)
        obj_content = blob.download_as_string()
        print("[" + obj + "]" + " downloaded object")
        obj_soup = BeautifulSoup(obj_content, "lxml")
        # Get env vars
        dotenv_path = os.path.join(dirname(__file__), ".env")
        load_dotenv(dotenv_path)
        DB_USER = os.environ.get("DB_USER")
        DB_PASS = os.environ.get("DB_PASS")
        DB_NAME = os.environ.get("DB_NAME")
        DB_CONN_NAME = os.environ.get("DB_CONN_NAME")
        # Connect to SQL db
        engine = create_engine(
            URL(
                drivername="mysql+pymysql",
                username=DB_USER,
                password=DB_PASS,
                database=DB_NAME,
                query={"unix_socket": "{}/{}".format("/cloudsql", DB_CONN_NAME)},
            )
        )
        # ... Code stops below here, no more print statements in the log ...
        ...
        return ("", 204)
    except Exception as e:
        return f"Error: {e}", 400

    return ("500 Error", 500)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    PORT = int(os.getenv("PORT")) if os.getenv("PORT") else 8080
    HOST = str(os.getenv("HOST")) if os.getenv("HOST") else "127.0.0.1"

    # This is used when running locally. Gunicorn is used to run the
    # application on Cloud Run. See entrypoint in Dockerfile.
    app.run(host=HOST, port=PORT, debug=True)
```

I get the following log output when I hit the service's endpoint:

> A 2020-07-16T14:42:37.810651Z [obj] request received
>
> A 2020-07-16T14:42:37.810710Z [obj] connecting to storage
>
> D 2020-07-16T14:42:37.859600180Z Container Sandbox: Unsupported syscall setsockopt(0xc,0x0,0xb,0x3ebcf19f9974,0x4,0xc). It is very likely that you can safely ignore this message and that this is not the cause of any error you might be troubleshooting. Please, refer to https://gvisor.dev/c/linux/amd64/setsockopt for more information.
>
> A 2020-07-16T14:42:37.968604Z [obj] downloaded obj
>
> W 2020-07-16T14:42:38.255479Z POST 400 319 B 2.8 s python-requests/2.23.0 https://endpoint.a.run.app/?obj=object-id&obj-bucket=object-bucket POST 400 319 B 2.8 s python-requests/2.23.0

It is clear that there are no more print statements below the third one ("downloaded obj"). The logging message is very nondescript -- in fact, it is listed as a warning and not an error in the logs. What may be happening such that the request returns 400? I'm not even sure the service is returning 400, as there is no "Error:" in the printed logs. There already exists a connection in the Cloud Run setup between the service and the SQL db, so I don't believe that is the issue. Any ideas?

Comment: Is it every request? Can you give an example HTTP request? I think you are not getting logs becaust the `return` is returning to the client, it is not logging anything in the application. You probably want to log the error before returning 400 to the client.

Comment: I'm sending the request using `requests.post("cloud_run_endpoint", params={"object-id": "objName", "object-bucket": "objBucket")`

Comment: @AndyShinn I added a print statement as you suggested and found the error. It should be `os.path.dirname` not `dirname`. Thanks!